# xfonts installation failed and apt compromised

Tags: 14.04, package-management, software-installation, system, aptitude

I started the installation of all the `xfonts` packages on my Ubuntu 14.04.1 system with

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-*
```

While extracting a package (one of the hundreds of the list), the system got blocked. The mouse cursor worked, but all the windows were locked and a click anywhere or any button had no effect.

After a forced restart, I can work normally, but now I can't use `aptitude`! If I try to install a package, it says

```
dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem
```

And if I run that command, Ubuntu gets blocked again, while processing `xfonts-100dpi` or a similar package (it is always the same).

Can this problem be fixed in any way?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install -f`. then try installing it again.

Comment: Maybe deleting the files in `/var/cache/apt/archives` can help --- in case there is some damaged file that is triggering bugs around.

Comment: Post the error message when you run sudo dpkg --configure -a

Comment: @Tim: `sudo apt-get install -f` produces again `dpkg  was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem`.

Comment: @Rmano: I deleted all the `xfonts-*` files in `/var/cache/apt/archives` and then tried to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, but the system blocked as before. Could I remove *all* the files in that folder without any further damages?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: it doesn't give me an error message. While processing a certain package (`xfonts-100dpi` or now `xfonts-misc`) it just freezes all the windows and the keyboard. I can only move the mouse cursor, but I can't click any button.

Comment: This seems quite a bad hang, smell of a corrupted disk. --- I would 1) backup; 2) delete all files in that directory; 3) reboot to single user and force a check on the filesystem --- and then try again.

Comment: I had problems with Grub to reboot to single user (maybe used a wrong syntax); anyway, from a live CD I deleted all the files in `/var/cache/apt/archives` (but not the subdirectory `partial`, which is empty), then I umounted the filesystem and made `sudo fsck /dev/mydevice -f`. The output is a list of the 5 steps and then  `/dev/mydev 362794/9773056 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 3145417/39062272 blocks`. Is this the same as your suggested procedure?